# ngRepeat with Table: Change a cell's display text

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have a list of mails which I want to show in a grid (`<table>`). Some of these mails have attachments. For their corresponding rows, I would like to show an attachment icon in the attachment column. For rest, it should be empty.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6s4Z5/

My template is as follows:

```
<table id="resultTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="columnId in schema.columnOrder">
                <img src="icon_attach.png" ng-if="columnId == 'hasAttachments'">
                {{schema.columns[columnId].displayText}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in results.mails">
            <td ng-repeat="columnId in schema.columnOrder">
                <img src="icon_attach.png" ng-if="columnId == 'hasAttachments' && row.hasAttachments">
                <span ng-if="columnId != 'hasAttachments'" >{{ row[columnId] }}</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

where `schema.columnOrder` is an array of columnIds to be shown in the table.

This template is working but is this the best way to implement this? Moreover, I have to add an extra `<span>` for `ng-if` statement. Can that also be removed?

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much can change it to something like:

```
<span ng-if='your check'><img src=''/>{{row[columnId}}</span>
```

Comment: for attachment cells, I don't want to show the text (true or false). for other cells, I want to show the text.

Comment: Create a directive that will encapsulate your display rules. This way in the future if you decide to display it differently then you can make changes to directive.

Answer (score 0):

You could set (in the controller) the value of the column hasAttachments to be the image you want to display there.

Comment: controller has `hasAttachments` value set to true/false for different mails. These values may be used for other computations. So, changing the value in it for only display purpose may not be the best solution. Also, I believe, I would need to use `ngSanitize` for adding html like this.

Comment: I would investigate using a filter which transforms true into an icon image for this column. Something in this direction: https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/app/js/filters.js